# If $f\colon X\to Y$ is an onto, continuous mapping and $X$ is Lindelöf then $Y$ is Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a onto, continuous mapping. Let $\left\{V_t\right\}_{t\in T}$ be a cover of $Y$; that is,

$$Y\subseteq\bigcup_{t\in T}V_t.$$

Therefore,

$$X=f^{-1}[Y]\subseteq\bigcup_{t\in T}f^{-1}[V_t].$$

Since $f$ is continuous, $\left\{f^{-1}[V_t]\right\}_{t\in T}$ is a (open) cover of $X$. As $X$ is Lindelöf, there is a countable set $S\subseteq T$ for which,

$$X\subseteq\bigcup_{s\in S}f^{-1}[V_s].$$

Therefore since $f$ is onto,

$$Y=f[X]\subseteq\bigcup_{s\in S}f\left(f^{-1}[V_s]\right)\subseteq\bigcup_{s\in S}V_s.$$

Hence, $\left\{V_s\right\}_{s\in S}$ is a countable subcover of $Y$. By definition, this implies $Y$ is Lindelöf.

---

Is the above correct?

Comment: You should edit the title. A mapping cannot be Lindelöf. Your proof is correct. Trust yourself!

Comment: @PaulFrost: Was worded poorly, how does it look now?

Comment: It is okay now!

Comment: @PaulFrost: Great, thanks for the suggestion and conformation on the proof!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is quite correct. I'll present a slightly different version of that proof:

let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $Y$. Then $\mathcal{U'}:=\{f^{-1}[U]\mid U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is an open (by continuity of $f$) cover of $X$ (if $x \in U$, $f(x)$ is covered by some $U \in \mathcal{U}$ and then $x \in f^{-1}[U]$ for that $U$).

As $X$ is Lindelöf, there is a countable $\mathcal{U''} \subseteq \mathcal{U'}$ that also covers $X$, which we can write as $\{f^{-1}[U_n]\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ for some sequence $(U_n)_n$ from $\mathcal{U}$, and then $\{U_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a countable subcover for $\mathcal{U}$ (any $y \in Y$ is equal to some $f(x), x \in X$ by ontoness, and $x$ is covered by some $f^{-1}[U_m]$, so that $y=f(x) \in U_m$, for that $m$ as well).